# Get subspace generated by vectors \Bbb{R}^3

Tags: linear-algebra

Get subspace generated by vectors: $v_1(1,2,0), v_2(3,0,1), v_3(2,2,-1).$

A possible solution could be:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3 & 2 & x \\
2 & 0 & 2 & y \\
0 & 1 & -1 & z
\end{bmatrix}$$ RREF:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & \frac{-2x+5y+6z}{8} \\
0 & 1 & 0 & \frac{2x-y+2z}{8}  \\
0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{2x-y-6z}{8} 
\end{bmatrix}$$
$V = {\{(x,y,z) \epsilon \Bbb{R}^3| x = \frac{-2x+5y+6z}{8}, y = \frac{2x-y+2z}{8}, z = \frac{2x-y-6z}{8}}  \}$

Is it correct?

Comment: Because when you RREF, you get the identity matrix, the span of those vectors is $\mathbb{R}^3$ itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those equations aren't really useful since you haven't solved for $x,y$, or $z$. But you're over-complicating the problem. The subspace is just all linear combinations of $v_1,v_2,v_3$. If you use coefficients $c_i$, then any vector can be written
$$c_1(1,2,0)+c_2(3,0,1)+c_3(2,2,-1)=(c_1+3c_2+2c_3,2c_1+2c_3,c_2-c_3).$$
Since $v_1,v_2,v_3$ are also linearly independent, this subspace is just $\Bbb R^3$. You can see this in several ways. For example,

$$-v_1+v_2+v_3=(4,0,0),\quad v_1-\frac{1}{4}(4,0,0)=(0,2,0),$$
$$\quad\text{and}-\frac12(4,0,0)-\frac12(0,2,0)+v_3=(0,0,-1),$$
so this subspace contains $(1,0,0)$, $(0,1,0)$, and $(0,0,1),$ which span $\Bbb R^3$.